# mouse position ajax - asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I am using the following to send mouse down position to two actions in my controller, the first make an image on the fly, the second send the image to the viewer:

```
   $("#container2").bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                                currentX = e.pageX;
                                currentY = e.pageY;
                                diffX = (currentX - startX);
                                diffY = (currentY - startY);
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/Home/Scale3D',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: {
                                        pX: diffX,
                                        pY: diffY,
                                        pZ: diffX * sThickness,
                                        udm: ++udm
                                    }
                                }).done(function (d) {
                                    image.src = '/Home/Rotate3DImage?udm=' + (++udm);
                               });
                            });
```

Here is the first action:

```
 public ActionResult Scale3D(float pX = 0, float pY = 0, float pZ = 0, int inc = 0)
        {
            DicomImage3D im = null;
           ......
            return Json(new { success = true, inc = inc }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Second action:

```
public ActionResult Rotate3DImage(int udm = 0)
    {
        FileContentResult data;
        ........
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            objImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            data = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
        }
        return data;
    }
```

The problem is there is a delay and some images don't show up; the second action does not execute until all first ajax commands are processed by the first action.  Is there a way to execute the second action when success is received.  I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#container2").bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                                currentX = e.pageX;
                                currentY = e.pageY;
                                diffX = (currentX - startX);
                                diffY = (currentY - startY);
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/Home/Scale3D',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: {
                                        pX: diffX,
                                        pY: diffY,
                                        pZ: diffX * sThickness,
                                        udm: ++udm
                                    },
                                    success: {
                                     // code here
                                     image.src = '/Home/Rotate3DImage?udm=' + (++udm);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
```

Comment: Thank you.   I changed  .done(function (d) { to success.  There still delay.